# Encoding issues (german Umlaut) with Excel/Java/Json

Tags: java, json, excel, utf-8, apache-poi

I have a little program in Java which reads contents from an .xlsx file and writes some of it into a new .json file.
In the .xlsx cells there are some strings with german Umlauts ("ä, ö, ü").

My problem:
If the program is running on MacOS everything works fine.
If the program is running on Windows, the Umlauts appear as question marks � on the generated .json file.

What I tried:
1. set the encoding of the Project text file in the IDE I'm working in (Eclipse) to UTF-8
2. set the encoding of the Excel file (on Windows) to UTF-8

Here's the basic structure of my code, using the libraries json simple, gson and apache-poi.

Read the .xlsx file:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
```

The function I use everywhere to read the contents of the cells `Row.getCell(index).getStringCellValue()`.

I put the read contents in a String Field of an Object of type `Spiel` and generate the corresponding .json file from this Object as follows:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Levels.json");

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
gson.toJson(spiel, writer);

writer.close();
```

As I said, everything runs fine when I run on Mac. 
There are Umlauts in the Excel file and when I open the generated .json file on TextEdit (as UTF-8 encoded file) they're displayed normally.

If I run on Windows and open the generated .json file on e.g. Wordpad, all the Umlauts are replaced by this sign �.

Since I need to run the program on Windows in the future, I really need to solve this issue. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: WordPad is probably the worst editor to use.  Try installing Notepad++ or Atom instead.  They can both render extended character sets and Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `FileWriter` doesn't allow you to specify the charset, and uses the platform default charset, which can be different for each. (And is "UTF-8" for MacOS, while it is Windows-settings-specific on Windows)

Instead use:

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("Levels.json"), 
                                       StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

(JSON always uses the UTF-8 charset per the JSON standard)